# PHP Display array element

Tags: php, arrays

Have array

```
Array ( 
    [3] => 
    stdClass Object ( 
        [term_id] => 3 
        [name] => Lietuviu 
        [slug] => lietuviu 
        [term_group] => 0 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 3 
        [taxonomy] => kalba 
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0 
        [count] => 7 
        [object_id] => 135 
    ) 
)
```

want display: [name] => Lietuviu , try `$var[3][name]`, but this not work

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Comment: `$var[3]` is an object, so `$var[3]->name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because that Array is actually an object. Put $var into this function:

```
function object_to_array($data) 
    {
      if(is_array($data) || is_object($data))
      {
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        { 
          $result[$key] = object_to_array($value); 
        }
        return $result;
      }
      return $data;
    }
```

Like so:

```
$realArray = object_to_array($var);
```

Comment: 1 more question how to search values in this array, can I use function  `in_array` ?

Comment: Yes you can, it just makes an array of the object you gave it. But I believe `in_array` doesnt work well with multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The value under the index `3` is a stdClass object, you will have to use the arrow operator `->` to get its values:

```
print $var[3]->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

As your `$var[3]` element is an object, you have to access its properties like this:

```
echo $var[3]->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use object_to_array as defined or access the value in following way:
`$var[3]->name`